# How to define the energy gap for systems which exhibit superposition?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition

Lets consider some system that's always in its ground state. If such a system can exhibit superposition (meaning its ground state could be a superposition state), then wouldn't that mean its energy gap (the energy gap between its ground and first exited state) would be arbitrarily small - for one could modify the ground superposition state only very slightly to get an energy that was slightly higher than the ground state energy?

Comment: You should try to write formulas, and *precise* text.

Comment: Note that "superposition" doesn't make much sense as such.  Superposition *of what*?  You need to specify a "chosen" basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The energy gap is the difference between the smallest and second smallest eigenvalue of a Hamiltonian.  The corresponding states are thus eigenstates, and therefore orthogonal.  This means that the first excited state is orthogonal to the ground state, i.e., it is *not* a small modification of the latter.